# How is the selective complexometric titration testing equation simplified?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, titration

When there is $\ce{N^m+}$ and $\ce{M^n+}$  metal ions in a solution with respective m and n charge,

$\ce{N^{m+}, M^{n+}}$ reacts with EDTA($\ce{Y}$) as follows:

$$\ce{N^m+ + Y^4- <=>  NY^{m-4}}$$

$$\ce{M^n+ + Y^4- <=>  MY^{n-4}}$$

Formation constant for each chemical reaction,

$$\ce{K_{NY^{m-4}}} = \frac{\ce{[NY^{m-4}]}}{\ce{[N^{m+}][Y^{4-}]}}$$

$$\ce{K_{MY^{n-4}}} = \frac{\ce{[MY^{n-4}]}}{\ce{[M^{n+}][Y^{4-}]}}$$

where as $\ce{N^m+}$ has the higher value for formation constent K<sub>NY<sup>m-4</sup></sub> > K<sub>MY<sup>n-4</sup></sub>

Fraction of each ion exsists ${α}$, $\ce{[N_{total}][M_{total}][Y_{total}]}$ are the total concentraion of the ion in any form.

$\ce{α_{Y^{4-}}}$ = $\frac{\ce{[Y^4-]}}{\ce{[Y_{total}]}}$
$\ce{α_{N^{m+}}}$ = $\frac{\ce{[N^m+]}}{\ce{[N_{total}]}}$
$\ce{α_{M^{n+}}}$ = $\frac{\ce{[M^n+]}}{\ce{[M_{total}]}}$

After $\ce{N^m+}$ has reacted with EDTA,the remaining amount EDTA is used for $\ce{M^n+}$

$$\ce{[Y^{'}_{total}] = [Y_{total}] + [NY^{m-4}]}$$

Where as $\ce{α_Y^{'}}$ is,

$$\ce{α_{Y^{'}}} = \frac{\ce{[Y_{total}]}}{\ce{[Y^{'}_{total}]}}$$

These are all the definition constants but I have no clue how this equation came

$$\ce{K''_{MY^{n-4}} = K_{MY^{n-4}}α_{M^{n+}}α_{Y^{4-}} - α_Y^{'}}$$

To perform a `selective complexometric titration` this condition need to be satisfied,

***$$\ce{K''_{MY^{n-4}} = K_{MY^{n-4}}α_{M^{n+}}α_{Y^{4-}} - α_Y^{'} \geq 10^7}$$***

where ***α<sub>Y'</sub>*** is given below,

***$$\ce{α_{Y'}} = \frac{1}{\ce{(1 + K_{NY^{m-4}}α_{N^{m+}}α_{Y^{4-}}[N_{total}])}}$$***
Using EDTA as for an example Y<sup>4-</sup>

How did this equation came with the assumptions (The simplified equation)

$$\ce{K''_{MY^{n-4}}} = \frac{K_{MY^{n-4}}α_{M^{n+}}α_{Y^{4-}}}{K_{NY^{m-4}}α_{N^{m+}}α_{Y^{4-}}[N_{total}]}$$

One of the assumptions would be

$$\ce{ K_{NY^{m-4}}α_{N^{m+}}α_{Y^{4-}}[N_{total}] \gg 1}$$

Addition of one can be neglected.

What are the assumption do need to use to get the simplified expression

Can someone help me just using basic mathematics did not help I tried it by myself but no luck I am pretty sure I have missed some `assumptions`

Comment: Can you reference the book?

Comment: What are all those variables ***K''***, ***K***, K, ***Y'***, $N_{total}$ etc.? Also, please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your posts competently with MathJax and Markdown.

Comment: I can define all the constants and respective chemical equations then the question will be very long?

Comment: Defined the constants now but $\ce{K''}$ is unknown

Comment: You have not involved acidobasic conditions, affecting [Y^4-]/[EDTA total] and pH changes due titration.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer to the question I have made a huge mistake in the testing equation

In order for a titration to happen the Formation constant $\ce{K}$ should be greater than or equal to $\ce{10^7}$

What I have written in my note book is

> $\ce{K''_{MY^{n-4}}} = \ce{K_{MY^{n-4}}α_{M^{n+}}α_{Y^{4-}}-α_{Y^{'}}}$

Which is incorrect it,

Should be like this

> $\ce{K''_{MY^{n-4}}} = \ce{K_{MY^{n-4}}α_{M^{n+}}α_{Y^{4-}}α_{Y^{'}}}$

The conditional formation constant of metal $\ce{M}$ should be multiplied by $\ce{α_{Y^{'}}}$ not ***subtracted***

Substituting the equation for $\ce{α_{Y^{'}}}$ will give the simplified equation

$$\ce{α_{Y^{′}}=  \frac{1}{(1+K_{NY^{m-4}}α_{N^{m+}}α_{Y^{4-}}[N_{total}])}}$$

$$\ce{K''_{MY^{n-4}} =  \frac{K_{MY^{n-4}}α_{M^{n+}}α_{Y^{4-}}}{(1+K_{NY^{m-4}}α_{N^{m+}}α_{Y^{4-}}[N_{total}])}} $$

But since

***$$\ce{K_{NY^{m-4}}α_{N^{m+}}α_{Y^{4-}}[N_{total}] >> 1 }$$***

***$$\ce{K_{NY^{m-4}}α_{N^{m+}}α_{Y^{4-}}[N_{total}] + 1 \approx K_{NY^{m-4}}α_{N^{m+}}α_{Y^{4-}}[N_{total}] }$$***

Which gives the following final simpified experssion

$$\ce{K''_{MY^{n-4}} =  \frac{K_{MY^{n-4}}α_{M^{n+}}}{K_{NY^{m-4}}α_{N^{m+}}[N_{total}]}} \geq 10^7 $$

Finally the testing equation is sloved for selective titrations